# What causes the failure to physically remove an image from the server in this Laravel 8 application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a Laravel 8 application that requires user registration and login.

Alter registration, the users have the possibility to replace the default avatar image with *a picture of their choice*. They are also able to *revert to the default avatar* (default.png).

A problem arises while trying to *remove the image file* itself from the server after delete.

In `routes\web.php` I have:

```
Route::post('/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/{id}/{fileName}', [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UserProfileController::class, 'deleteavatar'])->name('profile.deleteavatar');
```

In `Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UserProfileController.php` I have:

```
// Delete avatar
public function deleteavatar($id, $fileName) {
    $current_user = Auth::user();
    $current_user->avatar = "default.png";
    $current_user->save();

    if(File::exists(public_path('images/avatars' . $fileName))){
        File::delete(public_path('images/avatars' . $fileName));
    }
}
```

In `app.js`:

```
(function() {
    //Delete Avatar
    $('#delete-avatar').on('click', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var $avatar = $('#avatar-container').find('img');
        var $topAvatar = $('#top_avatar');
        var $trashIcon = $(this);
        var defaultAvatar = APP_URL + '/images/avatars/default.png';

        //Get user's ID
        var id = $(this).data('uid');
        var fileName = $avatar.attr('src').split('/').reverse()[0];

        if (confirm('Delete the avatar?')) {
            var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            $.ajax({
                url: APP_URL + `/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/${id}/${fileName}`,
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    fileName: fileName,
                    _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                },
                success: function() {
                    $avatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
                    $topAvatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
                    $trashIcon.remove();
                }
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

When I delete the user's avatar, the following happens:

1. The avatar *is* replaced with `default.png` in the `avatar` column of the **users** table.
2. The Chrome console shows a `500 (Internal Server Error)` error.
3. The image is NOT removed from the dearver.

What am I missing?

Comment: can you enable eror log .see what you get APP_DEBUG=true in .env

Comment: also where file exist .is it in storage/app/public ?

Comment: Did you check the error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you images in public folder then you have imported wrong File import

You should import

```
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
```

then i assume images are in `public/images/avatars/avatar.png`.

```
if(File::exists(public_path('images/avatars/' . $fileName))){
    File::delete(public_path('images/avatars/' . $fileName));
}
```

Suppose if you have files `storage/app/public/images/avatars` then you should do the following

```
if (Storage::exists('public/images/avatars/'. $fileName)) {
        Storage::delete('public/images/avatars/'. $fileName);
    }
```

Also don't forget to import right one

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

Comment: Oh, right. I think I forgot to import and use the right facade. I will check it out once I am at the computer.

Answer (score 0):

This method is dangerous but should be work:

In `Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UserProfileController.php` you can use @unlink for delete file an ignore errors, if your file exists will be deleted, and if not nothing occurs.

```php
// Delete avatar
public function deleteavatar($id, $fileName) {
    $current_user = Auth::user();
    $current_user->avatar = "default.png";
    $current_user->save();

    @unlink(public_path('images/avatars/' . $fileName));
}
```